# Let ℝ+ be the set of positive numbers. Determine all functions $f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ such that $f(x^2+xf(y)) = f(f(x))(x+y)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $\mathbb R^+$  be the set of positive numbers. Determine all functions $f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ such that $$f(x^2+xf(y)) = f(f(x))(x+y)$$ for all positive real numbers $x$ and $y$.

I think that the only solution is $f(x) = x$. But I'm not sure how to prove it.
I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Is this from a contest of some sort? As for the close votes and down vote you received, it seems that the community felt you didn't give enough context or show enough effort, though I myself can't really blame you since it's the type of question where you don't have a lot to work with to begin with. Still, some general advice (might not work every time) I would give you is to start with specific values, like $x = 1$, $y = 1$, $y = x$, $y = x^2$, among others, and see if you can find anything. You can also make some assumptions like $f(1) = 1$ and see where that leads you.

Comment: @BrunoB Yes, it's from Math Oly. Sorry for the lack of context and thanks for the advice! I'll definitely do that next time.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the only solution is $f(x)=x$.

First we claim that $f$ must be injective.  Indeed, if $f(x)=f(y)$, then we have
$$f(f(x))(x+y)= f(x^2+xf(y))=f(x^2+xf(x))=f(f(x))(x+x)\text{,}$$
and canceling (since we are in $\mathbb R^+$) gives $x=y$.

But now if $x+y=1$, we have
$$f(x^2+xf(y))=f(f(x))(x+y)=f(f(x))\text{,}$$
so by injectivity we get
$$x^2+xf(y)=f(x)\text{,}$$
and similarly
$$y^2+yf(x)=f(y)\text{.}$$
Using $y=1-x$ we can solve this system
\begin{align*}
x^2+x(y^2+yf(x)) &=f(x)\\
x^2+x\left((1-x)^2+(1-x)f(x)\right) &= f(x)\\
x^3-x^2+x &= f(x)(x^2-x+1)\\
x=f(x)\text{,}
\end{align*}
so that every $x<1$ is a fixed point of $f$.

But if $x$ is a fixed point, we also have $$f(2x^2)=f(x^2+xf(x))=f(f(x))(x+x)=2x^2\text{,}$$
and so the fixed point set includes $(0,1)$ and is closed under the map $\phi(x)=2x^2$. Since $\phi$ is continuous, and takes $0$ to $0$, the fixed point set includes $(0,\phi^n(1))$ for all $n$.  Since $\phi^n(1)\to\infty$, this completes the proof.